# What do we call this simple ragged-end cylindrical tool for making round holes in walls? It's a hand tool, to be hit by hammer

Tags: tools, terminology

I came across the Russian word **шлямбур** (shlyambur), describing this kind of tool for making holes in brick/concrete walls, but I can't seem to find the correct English term. The [entries in the Multitran dictionary](https://www.multitran.com/m.exe?l1=2&l2=1&s=%D1%88%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%80&langlist=1) seem to describe some different entities, because when I use Google Images on them, they all come up with different tools and things.

[image]

The tool is used manually, by hitting it with a hammer at the blunt end. In between hammer hits, it's rotated by hand to loosen up the material.

When I use GoogleTranslate on [a Russian page](http://www.remotvet.ru/questions/8866-chto-takoe-shljambur.html) describing the use of the tool, it comes up with the names "jumper" and "bolter", which is wrong. Here's a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0weiwgnLdLE) in which an improvised шлямбур is used to make a hole in a wall.

> [image]

The origin of the Russian term is presumably *Schlagbohrer*, a German word.

P.S. The Russian word for a climbing bolt is also **шлямбур** (a contraction of **шлямбурный крюк**), but it's a different tool. In the majority of cases, **шлябмур** is used at home, not in the mountains.

Googling for English-language climbing equipment, I only found this tool that has a similar shape, called "serrated self-drilling anchor". Maybe that's why climbing bolts are called in Russian **шлябмур**, by analogy, because probably initially these bolts were of this kind, self-drilling anchors.

> [image]

Comment: Would say a hand hole saw.  These days you would probably need to search though 99 pages to find one, most are for use in different types of drills.  Might find one on sites dealing with old tools.

Comment: Based on @crip659's suggestion, I'd go with something like "hand-held hammer-drill bit". After all, that's exactly what it is - a drill-bit that you hammer while holding by hand. Of course, "hand-held hammer-drill bit" isn't exactly a catchy marketing name, so you might not find it listed in the sales catalog by that name...

Comment: Not exactly. A **star drill** is the **hand-held hammer driven masonry/rock drill** common here. I keep referencing them when people come up with weird scenarios where they want to drill rocks wthout power drills ;^). It's not hollow, though. This is not a tool I've ever seen in this area. "hand-hammered core drill" might be a shot at describing it, in the local vernacular, to include it's hollow-ness.

Comment: Using search on the Russian word, the images seem to point to a tool used to set rock climbing anchors.  Use that tool to make a hole, and then the anchor is placed into the hole and expanded, like the common drywall/cement wall anchors.  Maybe someone on this site can give the English name.   https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @crip659 The Russian word for a climbing bolt is also шлямбур (a contraction of шлямбурный крюк), but it's a different tool.

Comment: Search images show шлямбурный крюк as what I called the anchor.  шлямбур seems to be the tool to make the hole for the шлямбурный крюк.  Imagine there are some rock climbers on the outdoor site that might know more about it.  Searching for either word/s will bring up images of both tools, so imagine they go together.

Comment: As a rock climber in North America, I have never seen a hollow core thingy like this. That said, Eastern Bloc climbers had a reputation back in the day for, shall we say, innovative climbing solutions.

Comment: Hammer core drill comes to mind, but best check the technical dictionaries as "ordinary" dictionaries don't do technical terms well at all.

Answer (score 2):

I'd call this a **hole saw**. Specifically, it's just a manual version of this (which comes in both wood, and masonry versions).

Note, the saw itself is the *hole saw* while the entire unit together is a "hole saw + arbor + pilot bit":
[image]

...Verily, it seems that in the English language, anything which is similar in shape and performs this function is named a **hole saw** : [image]

Comment: Perfect tool to drill drywall for toggle anchors, cable grommets, or anything that needs a hole that size in drywall.